# Query to count the number of orders before and including that order, but no new orders there after

Tags: sql-server, count

I have a report where I need to count the number of orders up to that order. Explained a bit differently, John placed an order 1234 and order 1234 is John's 4th order. John's next order 2345 is John's 5th order. It would have to use a counter, just not sure how to count ONLY up until that order, and not count any order there after effectively labeling each order as "This is John's XX order".

The results would look something like:

```
ORDER_ID | Customer_ID | Order_Count
1234     | 222         | 1
1235     | 211         | 1
1236     | 233         | 1
1237     | 222         | 2
1238     | 222         | 3
1239     | 211         | 2
```

The end goal is that we'll be able to look at trends relating to our customer's first order, 4th order, or XX orders.

Comment: Have you tried anything???

Comment: Without table structure, sample input, how do you think people can help you?

Comment: This is a guide how to ask question.  https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Just count the number of ORDER_IDs for the Customer_ID that are less than the currenct ORDER_ID.

Comment: We are going to need to see some sample data from your table to be able to write sql for this. We have no idea what your data looks like.

Comment: It sounds like you'll end up needing a `ROW_COUNT()`

Comment: Sorry, I guess I should have had an example script, but I got what I needed from the first Answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your table is keyed at the order (one row per order) then something like:

```
SELECT ORDER_ID, 
    Customer_ID, 
    COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY Customer_ID ORDER BY ORDER_ID ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW) AS Order_Count 
FROM yourtable
```